# Personal text for rand image

Tags: android, android-intent

Sorry for my English!
Have code like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String imgName="";
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:{
        Random rand = new Random();
        int rndInt = rand.nextInt(24) + 1;
        imgName = "img" + rndInt;
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());  
        imageView1.setImageResource(id);

        break;}

    default:
        break;
    };

}
```

How i can set in new intent by click on image description for my rand image ? Individual for each ?
Sample:
After I click button, rand image is fish. When I click on it, open new intent with text=Fish can swim!
Or rand image is cat, when i click on it, open new intent with text="Cat love to sleep. Cat hates dogs. But they so cute! (Bla bla bla bla bla bla)*10"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an `onTouchlistener` for your `imageView`. Then, in the `ACTION_DOWN` event check which random `imageResource` is set in the `imageView` and run the intent.

if you want to retrieve image resource name you can use:

```
String imageName = (String) imageView.getTag();
```

Now, to start a new activity with custom text:

```
if(imageName.equalsIgnoreCase("fish"))
   description="Fish lives in water..."
else if(imageName.equalsIgnoreCase("cat"))
   description="cat is cute..."
.
.
.
.
```

After evrything is compared, call your actvity,

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);
i.putExtra(description,"ID");
startActivity(i);
```

In your second activity retrieve the image description,

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String description = extras.getString("ID");
```

Comment: can example pls ? How we can check what image set ?

Comment: thnx! u rule!
1 more question:
Now need to putExtra in intent, in new activity getExtra and after use "if" and "equals" or somehow use "switch" ?
Thnx 1 more time!